# How to remove an instance of object from the list?

Tags: c#

I want to remove an instance of object from the list.

I've consulted Microsoft Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netcore-3.1) for the solution to my problem and this is the part I'm looking for:

```
// This will remove part 1534 even though the PartName is different,
// because the Equals method only checks PartId for equality.
parts.Remove(new Part(){PartId=1534, PartName="cogs"});
```

I want to enter the value of property Name, and remove an instance with corresponding name.

```
Console.Write("Enter name: ");
Name = Console.ReadLine();
//even though it doesn't make much sense to me, I've tried a few things, the latest being...
triangles.Remove(new Triangle(Name, A = 0) { Name = Name, A = 0 });
```

Comment: You can search the list for an instance (or instances) matching that criteria, then remove the instance(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered [RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netcore-3.1)?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestObject> myList = new List<TestObject>();
        myList.Add(new TestObject {ID=1, Name="Name"});

        myList.RemoveAll(x => x.ID == 1 && x.Name == "Name");
    }
}

//Just a dummy example class
public class TestObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

After the call to `RemoveAll`, the list will be empty (in this specific example).
Note that I'm also ignoring the returns value of `RemoveAll`. It returns an `int` representing the number of items removed, which may be helpful.